# Random color matrix in matlab

Tags: matlab, random, colors, octave, psychtoolbox

I would like to generate a matrix of random color blocks -- 10 by 10 pixel blocks of random colors -- such as:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jlc8L.png

So far, I have generated random numbers and enlarged the matrix with `kron`:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/eBU0T.png

using:

```
I = kron(randn([10 10]), ones(10));
imshow(I);
```

I would like to add random colors to this, but:

```
I = kron(randn([10 10 3]), ones(10));
```

reports:

```
error: invalid conversion of NDArray to Matrix
```

How can I generate a matrix of random color blocks?

This is for use with Psychtoolbox-3 (`DrawTexture` does not seem able to scale up a 10x10 random color matrix to 100x100 *without* interpolation).

Comment: You actually missed the `filterMode` flag in `Screen('DrawTexture')` (cf. http://docs.psychtoolbox.org/DrawTexture)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might as well generate the matrix directly:

```
    R = rand(10,10,3);
    figure;imshow(R);
```

In order to create a block matrix, use [`imresize`](http://www.mathworks.com.au/help/images/ref/imresize.html):

```
    Rb = imresize(R,10,'nearest');
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the way I usually do something similar, in case it helps:

```
R = rand(10,10);
subplot(1,1,1)
imshow(mat2gray(R(:,:,1)));
colormap jet
```

Where the colormap can be changed to any of Matlab's presets, or your own, to reflect the value in the matrix.

Answer (score 0):

The proper solution is to switch the interpolation algorithm for the particular texture.

Behind the scenes Psychtoolbox uses OpenGL, which allows you to fiddle with raw OpenGL commands between `MakeTexture` and `DrawTexture`.

roughly, from memory. Fill in the "blanks"

```
Screen('MakeTexture')
Screen('GetOpenGLTexture')
glTexParameterfv(target,GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER,GL_NEAREST);
Screen('DrawTexture')
```